# Linux CentOS 5.5 not connecting to Network

Tags: networking, centos

I have installed Linux CentOS 5.5.  During installation, I configured the LAN driver and gave it an IP address. After installation, I checked the network connection but it shows "not connected".

I then tried to enable dhcp (from broadband) but `system-config-network` shows

```
Determining IP information for eth0... failed; no link present. Check cable"
```

I checked the cable and everything is OK with it. I then added

```
check_link_down(){
return 1;
}
```

to `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` but `system-config-network` still shows the same message.

I have checked `service NetworkManager status` and `service network status` all is fine but I still can't connect to the network.

Comment: Does the output of `dmesg` or `/var/log/messages` show anything pertaining to the detection of the hardware for this NIC?

Comment: can you tell us what your NIC is, and which driver it is (or not) using?

Comment: @ MariusMatutiae I don't know what exactly my NIC is, It is HCL core i3 machine with inbuilt NIC

Comment: @ slm On dmseg it shows r8169: eth0: link down ; r8169: eth0: unknown chipset (mac_version=1); r8169: eth0: link down; ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready; r8169: eth0: link down

Answer (score 3):

Just try `mii-tool` to see if your cable has a signal:

```
user1@c55:~$ sudo mii-tool
eth0: negotiated 100baseTx-FD flow-control, link ok
```

Another way is using the tool`ethtool`, for debugging NIC (network ethernet card) problems.

Comment: Thanks for help.
I have used `mii-tool`.
it shows 

    SIOCGMIIPHY on 'eth0' failed: Operation not supported
    no MII iterfaces found