# How to setup automatic IP assignment after ethernet cable is plugged in

Tags: linux, centos, networking, ethernet

I have a Centos server and I have a problem with automatic detection of cable connection.
Whenever server is up before router has started i need to restart server to make it detect IP.

For Example:
- I bootup server.
- No network is connected (cable unplugged or router down),
- Start router or plug in cable.
- Connection is not detected. Server needs a restart.

How to configure (console) server to watch for cable plug-in event?

Ifconfig output:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:14:85:EE:7D:D9
          inet addr:192.168.1.15  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::214:85ff:feee:7dd9/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:33127 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:37421 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:6348000 (6.0 MiB)  TX bytes:33946404 (32.3 MiB)
```

`cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` output:

```
# Intel Corporation 82801EB/ER (ICH5/ICH5R) integrated LAN Controller
DEVICE=eth0
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
ONBOOT=yes
HWADDR=00:14:85:ee:7d:d9
```

chkconfig (I use level 3):

```
/sbin/chkconfig --list network
network         0:off     1:off     2:On      3:On      4:On      5:On      6:off
/sbin/chkconfig --list NetworkManager
NetworkManager  0:off     1:off     2:off     3:off     4:off     5:off     6:off
```

Comment: What version of CentOS do you have?

Comment: Does your `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/<interface>` contain the following: `onboot=yes` and `bootproto=static`, I am assuming here that since this is a server that your using a static IP and not DHCP (else bootproto should be equal to dhcp).  You can compare your setup to the one provided [here](https://wiki.centos.org/FAQ/CentOS7#head-a21a9e454157700367c9b7e9ccb1ff9954bec881).

Comment: Centos is 5.10.
Router > local static IP  (it's dev server)
`bootproto=dhcp` and `onboot=yes`

Comment: So you have a server that is assigned and ip address with DHCP, that is ... uhh, special :-) Check out the answer to [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131351/how-to-see-if-an-interface-is-connected-in-centos-linux). See if anything there helps you out. Note that information to these commands are only relevant to you while the network cable is connected and no network is showing up (so you need physical access to it).

Comment: If you only have access to the server through ssh, can you be sure that it is always getting the 192.168.1.15 address assigned to it with DHCP?

Comment: You can also try the `mii-tool` like is described [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97009/linux-centos-5-5-not-connecting-to-network?rq=1)

Comment: As I said, its a local dev server. Only in local network ;) So I dont think its unusual. I saw this post before i posted this question. It's assigned by DHCP on MAC adres. This address is reserved on DHCP to this MAC.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. But I think your going to have to hook up a screen and keyboard to it and see what is going on there when the cable gets connected but no connection gets initiated.

Comment: Please add the output of `/sbin/chkconfig --list network` and `/sbin/chkconfig --list NetworkManager` to your question.

Comment: @Bram Probably this is the case! I run it on lvl 3 and networkmanager is off for this level.

Comment: If you're system runs in a localized language setting you can prefix the command with `LC_ALL=en_US` to get the output in English, like `LC_ALL=en_US /sbin/chkconfig --list network`.  That makes it easier for non-Polish speakers to know that `włączone` means enabled without resorting to google translate. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be exactly what `NetworkManager` was designed for.

Make sure NetworkManager is installed and the service running and stop the old `network` service.

By the way even with the `network` service rebooting is not necessary. A restart of that service should trigger a new dhcp request. But NetworkManager should do that automatically when it detects the cable is plugged in.

Comment: It's only remote management server. No keyboard nor mouse nor monitor. So only restart is what's left as I can't login via SSH to it if interface is down. going to test it now.

Comment: NetworkManager-0.7.0-13.el5.i386 already installed and latest version

Comment: To clarify: Network manager was installed but service was not enabled on runlevel (3) i'm using.

Comment: how would one, say, ssh into an instance and re-enable network manager if stopping 'network' first is required? it'll cut the ssh once you do it...